# File Not Found - But no File Specified

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, custom-error-pages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to solve exception “File does not exist”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705057/how-to-solve-exception-file-does-not-exist)

My Asp.NET web application is throwing errors. The date and time of the errors do not seem to correspond to a date and time when a page is being loaded.

I am using a custom error page, but as far as I can tell this is not being diaplayed.

Here is the customErrors section of the web.config:

```
   <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/WebForms/ErrorPage.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/WebForms/ErrorPageNotFound.aspx" />
   </customErrors>
```

The full error and stack trace is as follows:

```
06/08/2012 01:15:25 - Error File does not exist.
   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context, String overrideVirtualPath)
   at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

As you can see it says File does not exist but does not tell me which file. I would be grateful if someone could shed any light on this and point in a direction to start looking.

Comment: When do you get this error? When you go to the root of your web site? (`/`)?

Comment: It's probably happening when there is an exception in your app and asp.net is trying to find the error page. Can you add the web.config code where you set it?

Comment: Related thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705057/how-to-solve-exception-file-does-not-exist

Comment: @Jacob - I can't re-create the error at will. It seems to happen around 1-2 times a day but like in the example this happened at 01:25am when I would be very surprised if any pages were being processed

Comment: @avd - Thanks for the link - I think this is a duplicate of that question so I will vote to close as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in my comments this is a duplicate question.

The error was being caused by a request to `favicon.ico` in the root of my website which did not exist.

I suspect that my site was being trawled by a search engine spider or such which is why the errors happened at strange times.

Update: There was another occurrence of this last night with a request for `robots.txt`