# Error in Global ASAX: File Does Not Exist

Tags: asp.net, debugging

I am trying to understand what error occurred that sent me to the Global ASAX OnError handler.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace GLSS.Components.HttpModules
{
  public class ExceptionModule : System.Web.IHttpModule 
  {
    private void OnError(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

      //get the last error
      Exception ex = context.Server.GetLastError();
      if(ex.InnerException.GetType().ToString() == "CSLA.DataPortalException")
        ex = ex.InnerException;
```

Here is my Exception converted to a String

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError().Message
"File does not exist."
HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError().StackTrace
"   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response)
at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)"
```

How do I determine what line of code is causing this error? I tried to set my Debug options to break when the error occurs, but it didn't , I still end up in the ONERROR global handler.

One thing is that I see that the code assumes that there will be an Inner Exception, and this appears to be NULL and is causing a second error within the handler.

I assume that the error is occuring somewhere in compiled code. I checked the Web.Config, and the only paths mentioned there is a Log Path, and that seems valid and logging appears to be working.

**Update**
I found some additional information here:

[How to solve exception "File does not exist"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705057/how-to-solve-exception-file-does-not-exist)

When I check this in the Immediate window:

```
? HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()
"http://localhost:2322/favicon.ico"
```

However, what puzzles me is that I search my entire solution looking for favicon.ico using "Find In Files" and I see no reference.

Why am I getting an error that the icon file is not found when I see no reference to it? I'm guess some assembly is using it? But why is it looking for it in the web root?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The request for favicon.ico is being blindly made by most modern browsers and they are expecting a *404 (File Not Found)* if there is no favicon (this is proper behaviour). Below you can find a quote from HTML5 working draft regarding [Link type "icon"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/links.html#rel-icon)
:

> In the absence of a link with the icon keyword, for documents obtained
>   over HTTP or HTTPS, user agents may instead attempt to fetch and use
>   an icon with the absolute URL obtained by resolving the URL
>   /favicon.ico against the document’s address, as if the page had
>   declared that icon using the icon keyword.

The reason why you see the exception is that the web development server or IIS configured to use *Managed/Integrated Pipeline Mode* puts all requests through *Global.asax* (including errors).

You can try to prevent the browsers from making the requests by creating following dummy link to favicon:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
        ...
    </head>
...
</html>
```

You also might try one of following:

- Add following line at beginning of `RegisterRoutes` method:

  `routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");`

  or even more extended version:

  `routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new {favicon=@"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?"});`
- Create yourself an empty file for favicon
- Filter out the errors by checking `HttpException.GetHttpCode()` for *404* and `((System.Web.HttpApplication)Sender).Context.Request.Url` for */favicon.ico*.